# Return Url not redirecting to defined page

Tags: asp.net, .net

I have an application that sends email to customers.
The content of the mail has a link to a download page with 3 parameters

i.e. 
"https://myurl.com/Products/Pages/Download.aspx?prd=0&typ=0&id=0"

I want to redirect the customer first to a login page before automatically downloading the item. The link that is programmatically generated is like this:

"https://myurl.com/Pages/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=/Products/Pages/Download.aspx?prd=2&typ=1&id=153"

But, after the user is authenticated, it doesn't go to the download page. What is wrong with the URL?

Appreciated any help...

Comment: Can you post the code you are using for the redirect?

Comment: Are you doing a `Response.Redirect` or a `Server.Transfer` or anything to actually perform a redirect?

Comment: nope. this is from the content in email that has a link to the item to download

Answer (score 0):

When you build the `ReturnUrl`, you need to encode it:

```
var url = "....ReturnUrl=" + Server.HtmlEncode(returnUrl);
```

Answer (score 0):

problem seems with url not finding the page

try with changing

```
https://myurl.com/Pages/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=/Products/Pages/Download.aspx?prd=2&typ=1&id=153
```

to

```
https://myurl.com/Pages/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=Products/Pages/Download.aspx?prd=2&typ=1&id=153
```

or you can manually create path using Server.MapPath

Comment: I think this along with @The Solution's answer is probably the right combination